# Is there a ressource that evaluates the quality of webfonts?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

I am a web developer, for a current project I use the font the designer has asked to purchase (the company CI font), but in my opinion it looks hard to read. I want to argue why this is a good or bad font and what would be a better one, but could not find a ressource on the internet that evaluates fonts on their fitness for certain purposes. Do anybody know one?

I am looking for something like http://caniuse.com/ . A simple table that tells me if the font in question is good for headings, for long text, what feeling one can achieve with a certain font etc.

Comment: Hi Teetrinker, welcome to GD.SE! I have never heard of a tool that can measure the readability of a font but check out some similar questions that talk about the readability of a font: [“Serifs improve fast, easy readability for long text” - myth or truth?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10778/serifs-improve-fast-easy-readability-for-long-text-myth-or-truth) and [Best fonts for improving reading experience](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26169/best-fonts-for-improving-reading-experience)

Comment: Also see: [Legibility of familiar fonts vs. typical considerations for typeface legibility](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61834/legibility-of-familiar-fonts-vs-typical-considerations-for-typeface-legibility).

Comment: Hi Teetrinker, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: There is a very important thing to remember when crossing the line from coding to design. Coding is mainly science, part art. Design is mostly art with a bit of science mixed in. What I want to say is that there is most probably no *exact* and *authoritative* way to determine the quality or legibility of a typeface&mdash;that's up to things like the type treatment, the surroundings and even subjective factors (*shudder* :) ) like personal taste and preference.

Answer (score 2):

There really is no 'bad' font. There are plenty of fonts, however, that are a bad choice in a lot of situations.

Point being, what makes a font good or bad has as much to do with how, where and why it's being used as much a it has to do with the font itself.

So, in a particular context, a font might be perfect, in another context, that same font, might be a poor choice.